# PHP contact form email random confirmation number to user

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a php contact form, and when the user submits the form, both me and the user is sent a confirmation email. What I would like to do is generate a random confirmation number, and email to both the user and me for reference. Here is the code that I have to generate the random number:

```
 <p>Your confirmation number is: <strong><?php echo mt_rand(100000,999999);?></strong>. Keep this for your records.</p>
```

The number displays on the form, but my problem is that I don't know how to output this number so that it can be emailed. Please forgive me I'm not a programmer, but I do have some very basic php knowledge. So if someone can help me out with this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here is the form on my school website: http://www.inrf.uci.edu/facility/services/service-request/

Here is also the some php code from my form:

```
    // name
    if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
        $nameError = '<span class="error">Please enter your name.</span>';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }
    // email
    if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
        $emailError = '<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $emailError = '<span class="error">You entered an invalid email address.</span>';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }



    // body ------------------------------------------
    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
        if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
            $emailTo = 'myemail@email.com';
        }
        $subject = '[Foundry Form] From '.$name;

        $body .= "Name: $name \n\n";
        $body .= "Email: $email \n\n";
        $body .= "Phone: $phone \n\n";

        $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: . $email';
        $headers .= "\r\n" . 'BCC: myotheremail@email.com' . "\r\n";

        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }




  }


}


?>


<div id="bodyPage" class="clear">
<!------- start body ------->
<section id="contentPage">
  <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>


 <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
        <div class="thanks">
          <p><strong>Thank You for Submitting a Service Request!</strong></p>
          <p>An INRF Staff Member will contact you shortly.</p>
          <p>If you do not receive a confirmation e-mail within 1-2 business days, you may contact us directly at (949) 824-2819 or <a href="mailto:info@inrf.uci.edu">info@inrf.uci.edu</a>.</p>
          <p>We look forward to serving your research needs!</p>


           <hr style="border:1px dashed #CCC;" />
          <?php
             echo "<Strong>Your Service Request information</strong><br>";
             echo "(You may print this page for your records)<br><br>";
             echo "<u>Contact Information</u><br>";
             echo "Name: ".$name;
             echo "<br>";
             echo "Email: ".$email;
             echo "<br>";

?>

        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
        <p class="error">Sorry, an error occured. See below.<p>

          <?php } ?>


           <?php if($captchaError != '') { ?><span class="error"><?=$captchaError;?></span><?php } ?>


     <script type="text/javascript">var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : 'white'};</script>

        <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="foundryForm" method="post">
          <strong>Contact</strong> <br />
          <br />
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td><label for="contactName">*Name:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" size="40" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="required requiredField" />
                <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                <span class="error">
                <?=$nameError;?>
                </span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="email">*Email:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" size="40" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="required requiredField email" />
                <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                <span class="error">
                <?=$emailError;?>
                </span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>


          </table>


    <br /><br /> 

      <?php
          require_once('scripts/recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "6LfR0eESAAAAAFtSdYmpqqVnVwP8ZMHCr--BIu5f"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>

          <p><input type="submit"></input></p>
          <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
        </form>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Too much code. Can you limit it to what's actually relevant?

Comment: Sure sorry about that:

Comment: What happens when two different people get the same confirmation number?

Comment: My question was really meant to be rhetorical, but I was curious about the odds of picking a repeat from that range so I wrote a little test program. Turns out, on average, you only need to pick 1189 times before you get a repeated number. That's pretty damn low. If the confirmation number is not something that the user ever has to speak over the phone, you're probably much better off using something like a UUID.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is create the confirmation number before you send the email:

```
$confirmationNumber = mt_rand(100000,999999);
```

Then add this to the body of the email:

```
$body .= "Confirmation Number: $confirmationNumber\n\n";
```

Then use `$confirmationNumber` when displaying on the page:

```
<p>Your confirmation number is: <strong><?php echo $confirmationNumber; ?></strong>. Keep this for your records.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! But the only thing is that the number that appears on the page is different than the number that is emailed to the user. Is there any way it can generate the same number?

Comment: Yes, just use `$confirmationNumber` when displaying. See my edit.